# is there a place to request feedback for analysis I've already done on a complex issue

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

I've had a complex issue involving strange wait types, VM ware, deadlocks,existing code and more.  I've done in depth analysis and I think I've figured it out based on a ton of research.

I'd like to sort of open it up to see if I've missed anything or I'm just plain wrong in my statement regarding how SQL works.

I suspect there is nowhere to post it (other than my own blog, not yet fully functional)or bugging a friend :) ,  but I thought I'd ask.

Answer (score 12):

I don't see any problem with posting it as a question at the site. We love complex issues!

Depending on how sure you are about your analysis results:

- if you are not very sure about your findings: 
  one question with two parts (within the question): the problem and your analysis/results.
  Others can answer if there are any flaws with your analysis and methodology.
- if you are almost sure about your results, post the problem as
  a question (with enough info so others could answer as well) and
  a separate answer with your analysis, findings and results.